# best ide for flex development

Tags: apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best (most productive) FLEX IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311887/what-is-the-best-most-productive-flex-ide)

i am new to flex. which ide is best for development

Comment: I voted to close.  Best is often subjective; and without having more parameters this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I voted to close as well.  Please search the VERY large database of questions before posting another that's been overdone to death.  Several duplicates out there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418058/free-flex-ides/5421331#5421331

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are a student then you get adobe flash builder 4 for free:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/free/

Comment: can you give the link for download flash builder for students?

Answer (score 4):

- [FDT](http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/) is the probably most powerful IDE (in its *Max* version)
- [Adobe Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/) is the best option for "normal" use (i.e. when you don't need all the features from FDT; you can do everything you need with Flash Builder)
- [Flash Develop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/) is the OpenSource alternative, and is free, but lacks many useful features

It should be noted though that you can develop the same software with any of those programs; you can even do it with a simple text editor. But of course each of those programs offer tools that can speed up the development process.

Personally I use Flash Builder and I would recommend anyone to use that one. While some of the features of FDT Max are really interesting, the price is rather high and compared with Flash Builder the other versions just don't offer really important things (like the debugger). In addition, if you work with any other Adobe software, you'll love that Flash Builder integrates well with the other software, and there are other great tools like Flash Catalyst that work hand in hand with Flash Builder.

Comment: For sake of completeness; don't forget about IntelliJ or Amethyst (A Visual Studio Plugin) or Ensemble Tofino (Another Visual Studio Plugin).  I know that Amethyst offers ability to debug both .NET and Flex code in the same debug ssesion; which would be a killer feature if you use .NET.

Answer (score 3):

Best IDE For flex. [Flash builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/).