# What are the editors to code with flex?

Tags: apache-flex, ide, editor

I want to code with flex. I know that Flash Builder can do it, but it is very huge for disk space. So I want to know if there are other editors for flex.

Comment: This kind of questions are generally off topic on StackOverflow, but you should visit this link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/2.+Setting+up+IDEs+%28optional%29

Comment: IntellJ; FDT; FlashDevelop and you can always use command line tools to compile/debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tell you that the page there are some entries for this topic.

[Go to Page stackoverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311887/what-is-the-best-most-productive-flex-ide)

[Go to Page stackoverflow 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418058/free-flex-ides/5421331#5421331)